# How to display PostgreSQL System variables

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am looking for a bash utility such as mysqladmin that could list all system variables values on the Postgres running instance.

Is there an utility that could be used as mysqladmin : `mysqladmin -pxxxxx variables`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*postgres system variable*"? Are you referring to configuration properties?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like, say:

```
psql -qAtc 'select * from pg_settings';
```

?

or, if you just want key/value:

```
psql -qAtc 'SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings';
```

?

Note that these will show settings *as they apply to the current user running the command*. So if there are `ALTER DATABASE ... SET ...` or `ALTER USER ... SET ...` options in effect you'll see those values, not the underlying ones from `postgresql.conf`.

For more details on formatting and control over output, see `man psql`.

If you want human-readable output rather than machine-friendly output, use `psql -qc`, leaving out the `-At` (meaning "unaligned, tuples-only").

Comment: great that's what i was looking for, and did not find anything on google. Thanks